# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"COUNTRY") Expected elements are <{http://www.w3schools.com}COUNTRY>

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd

Xml content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COUNTRY xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com Country_Details.xsd">

    <STATE name="AndhraPradesh">
        <DISTRICT name="Chittoor">
            <PHONENO>255258</PHONENO>
            <ADDRESS>bazarr Street</ADDRESS>
        </DISTRICT>
        <DISTRICT name="Kadapa">
            <PHONENO>24137457</PHONENO>
            <ADDRESS>congtres Street</ADDRESS>
        </DISTRICT>
    </STATE>
    <STATE>
        ...
    </STATE>
</COUNTRY>
```

This is my country class
**Country.java**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

@XmlType(name = " ", propOrder = { "state" })

@XmlRootElement(name = "COUNTRY")

public class COUNTRY {

    @XmlElement(name = "STATE", required = true)
protected List<Districts> state;

    public List<Districts> getSTATE() {
        if (state == null) {
            state = new ArrayList<Districts>();
        }
        return this.state;
    }
}
```

**Package Info:**

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.w3schools.com",
elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.kk;
```

Main class

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(AddressDetails.class,
        COUNTRY.class, Details.class, Districts.class, ObjectFactory.class);
    Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
    JAXBElement<COUNTRY> jaxb = (JAXBElement<COUNTRY>) um
        .unmarshal(new File("src//Country.xml"));
    COUNTRY value = jaxb.getValue();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

**I got error like this:**

```
Exception in thread "main"
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:unexpected element(uri:"", local:"COUNTRY"). 
Expected elements are <{http://www.w3schools.com}COUNTRY>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent
        (UnmarshallingContext.java:642)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:254)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement
(Loader.java:116)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:1049)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:459)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:148)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)

    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at App.main(App.java:20)
```

dont know where the fault is, I tried a lot, but I am unable to figure it out..

Answer (score 9):

Based on your mappings the JAXB impl expects the XML document to be namespace qualified.  You can fix it in one of the following ways:

1. Add the namespace qualification to the XML document.

   ```
    <COUNTRY xmlns="http://www.w3dchools.com">
   ```
2. Remove the namespace metadata from the JAXB mappings.  You have specified it using the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation.

   - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html
3. Use an `XmlFilter` to apply the correct namespace information to your current XML document.

   - [JAXB unmarshal with declared type does not populate the resulting object with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17214930/jaxb-unmarshal-with-declared-type-does-not-populate-the-resulting-object-with-da/17216995#17216995)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..  I tried second option, and I got this exception:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.kk.COUNTRY cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
 at App.main(App.java:20)

Comment: @user2523808 - Since your `Customer` class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement` the result will be an instance of `Customer` and not `JAXBElement<Customer>`.  For a full explanation see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html